# Execution order of javascript load/ready events of main page wrt embedded iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dom-events

With my somewhat limited JavaScript knowledge I'm trying to get a particular script execution order nailed.  I'm using JQuery for this.

I have a main page using JQuery which, when it is fully loaded, dynamically adds an iframe, in which it loads an extra page.  I want another piece of script in the main page to run once the initial scripts in the extra page have fully ran.  (So just the regular inline scripts, I don't care about setTimeout scripts in the extra page).  The extra page always registers it's script to run using JQuery's `$(document).ready` (it's something I have no control over).

What I ended up with and what works for me in FireFox and Edge is this:

Main page:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      console.log('main: loading')
      $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('main: ready')
        let iframeElement = $('<iframe></iframe>').appendTo($('body'))
        iframeElement.on('load', function() {
          console.log('main: iframe loaded')
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('main: after iframe loaded')
          }, 0)
        })
        iframeElement.attr('src', 'extra.html')
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>Main</body>
</html>
```

Extra page:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      console.log('extra: loading')
      $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('extra: ready')
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>Extra</body>
</html>
```

In FireFox the events are logged in this order:

1. main: loading
2. main: ready
3. extra: loading
4. main: iframe loaded
5. extra: ready
6. main: after iframe loaded

I don't give a hoot for 3 and 4, but what's important for me is that 6 always fires after 5.  The only way I could get it to work that way is by both registering a handler using `on('load')` on the iframe instead of using JQuery's `ready` on it, *and* using `setInterval` in that handler to further delay the handler.  If I do it any other way, 5 and 6 get inverted.

I just read up on the `defer` option for loading scripts, which does seem promising, but I can't control it's usage (I only have control over a single JavaScript file that is loaded in the main page).  And to my current knowledge the page's `onload` event fires after JQuery's `ready` event, which in turn occurs at an equivalent time as the `DOMContentReady` event, right?  But it's mainly the parallel event order between the two pages involved here I'm quite unsure of.

So what I fail to grasp is if this is the correct way to do it, and whether there are more sure-fire / correct ways to achieve the same.  And whether it works in Chrome too, since I haven't installed that thing on this laptop :)  And ofc any other tips wrt my (ab)use of JavaScript are welcome too :)

Comment: Don't use alert for debugging. It is a blocking method

Comment: @charlietfl: thanks, you're right ofc.  and console.log also makes for easier copy/paste of the results to StackOverflow :)  I've updated the post to use that.